# Returning only unique occurrences from a list of lists based on the first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

Apologies, I believe this is a common question, but cannot seem to find an exact answer for the desired outcome.

I would like to return ONLY the unique items in a list of lists based on one element.

Example;

```
List = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,4],[1,5],[6,3]]
```

Desired outcome;

```
List = [[2,3],[6,3]]
```

As 1 exists as the first element in several list items, I would like all of them disregarded.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What are the rules? How do you know to keep `[2, 3]` and not `[1, 2]` or `[1, 4]`? What do you mean "based on the first element"? What about the first element tells us whether to keep or throw out another element?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If I may, I think this question is pretty clear. Every tuple with `1` as the first element is disregarded because there are multiple sublists with `1` as the first element.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it is explained in the question: *As 1 exists as the first element in several list items, I would like all of them disregarded*. `2` and `6` appear in only one couple as the first (index 0) element so they are desired

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be tempting to use `list.count` but it will make the solution using it O(n^2) if used naively.

An O(n) solution would be using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

nested_list = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,4],[1,5],[6,3]]

counter_map = Counter(sublist[0] for sublist  in nested_list)
print(counter_map)
output = [sublist for sublist in nested_list if counter_map[sublist[0]] == 1]
print(output)
```

outputs

```
Counter({1: 3, 2: 1, 6: 1})
[[2, 3], [6, 3]]
```